# Express js custom date format function

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi i need a common function which should be able to convert date fields in two ways:

1. When i send data from client to server
2. When i receive data from server to client

Actually when i send data from client to server there are 5 to 10 date fields in each transaction this date fields are in Javascript Date object so when i save directly this values to Mysql it doesn't accept in date fields so i need to convert them to dd-mm-yyyy. In the second case we i fetch the data from database and display on Front end i am using date pickers which accepts only Javascript Date object. So here my problem is i need to convert each date field two time.
I want a common function which can convert date fields depending on transaction mode and this function should be capable to take names of all date files so each time i should not call the function i should call it at once at a time.

**__EDIT__**

I am using this function at server side form saving date in Mysql

```
function convertDateInDBFormate(timestamp) {
    //If input date is not valid date then assign a default value
    if((new Date(timestamp)).getTime() > 0){
        var date = new Date(timestamp);
        return (date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 01) + '-' + date.getDate()  );
    }
    else{
        return '1900-01-01';
    }
}
```

and at client side i am using Angulat $filter for date conversion but i want to do both at server side using a single function.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ADyson can see now what i tried.

Comment: so you are using node.js server-side?

Comment: have you considered using Moment.js? (http://www.momentjs.com) - it's ideal for working with dates and outputting in different formats